# Is there any way to find out whether we have opened page in Touch UI or classic UI in javascript

Tags: aem

Is there any way to find out whether we have opened this page in Touch UI or classic UI in javascript

like we have in classic UI to find out whether page is in edit mode or design mode.

```
CQ.WCM.editMode
```

Please suggest.

Answer (score 3):

If you are not restricting to determine ui mode within javascript, here are other ways:

1. If you have a model class for your component, check for this
   condition:

   ```
   AuthoringUIMode.TOUCH.equals(AuthoringUIMode.fromRequest(getRequest()))
   ```
2. To check from JSP, use this code:

   ```
   Placeholder.isAuthoringUIModeTouch(slingRequest)
   ```

Answer (score 2):

You can simply read the cookie value of `cq-authoring-mode`. It can either be `CLASSIC` or `TOUCH`.

```
var isTouch = $.cookie('cq-authoring-mode') === 'TOUCH'
```

The other way would be to look for an outstanding JS objects like `Granite.UI`. This might be painful in the future when the clientlib that created the object will be attached to the other mode (e.g. via an AEM hotfix or unconsciously during the development).

```
var isTouch = Granite.UI != null
```